# Youtube api find streams

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get a list of people who are currently streaming on YouTube using YouTube API.

However looking at the API it looks like im only able to fetch content that is either: `video, channel, playlist`

My question is: Is there a way to find stream videos and their associated links?

Comment: I second this... can't find how to query by tags